# ffmpeg setting up in wamp on localhost

Tags: php, ffmpeg, wamp, wampserver

I have done the following:

1. Downloaded ffmpeg from  http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/
2. Copied php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the

   `C:\wamp\bin\php\ext`
3. Copied files from common to the `windows/system32` folder
4. Added the `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll` to `php.ini` file
5. Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)
6. enabled `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll` directive in my `php.ini`.

But it still doesn't show up when I do a php info page. I thought it might have something to do with that fact that I'm using php version 5.3.0. I have googled for a `php_ffmpeg.dll` for php version 5.3.0 and haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ffmpeg software on to the system first, before installing http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/ this?

Comment: I seemed to have fixed it in a way, I had to use php 5.2.8 instead of php 5.3